# Is there a program to record CPU load and later converting it into an image?

Tags: linux, monitoring

I want to add a system usage diagram to our CI build server for our management so they can see that we need to buy a larger build server when the time has come

Should just save a png or svg image that occurred during last build.

Is there any simple program to do this?
I don't want to add a whole prometheus/grafana pipeline setup to the build process.

Comment: Arguably you simply need monitoring with history retention. And you run that 24x7  independently of what your server is doing and when . Recording the load only during builds, when your load peaks is not really saying much. I wouldn’t give you a better server without also knowing how long your build takes and if that is slowing down, how many builds you do and how long you sit twiddling your thumbs waiting for a build to finish and other usage and performance metrics.

Comment: That question has been asked before, with several [suggestions](https://serverfault.com/questions/70051/a-simple-option-for-graphing-cpu-usage-on-a-remote-linux-server).

Comment: @HermanB  of course i already have this metrics about build times, build configurations  and build runs.  I just need CPU load (and parallelism control as hint for unit test writers). And i want to save this with the CI report.

Comment: @berndbausch  Thanks, i will look at Munin tonight, maybe you are right and it does exactly what i want.

Comment: You may find that sar is already running routinely (particularly on a RHEL-like distribution, not sure about Debian-like distributions). It doesn't have graphing capabilities, but it would be easy to include in CI reports.

Comment: Indeed, you should also check out gnuplot based on sar data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in to comments you can use `sar` which is part of `sysstat` package. To create graph from this data you can use [ksar](https://github.com/vlsi/ksar), [RRDtool](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/), [sargraph](https://github.com/sargraph/sargraph.github.io) and probably a lot of other software

Answer (score 0):

You may find `atop` useful: https://www.atoptool.nl/netatop.php. When installed, it automatically collects historical data and provides basic reporting capabilities via `atopsar`.

I've also just found this tool which can be used to create graphs from atop metrics: https://github.com/aplsms/atop-graph

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortuantely after a short github browing i get the feeling that atop-graph is pulling in too much dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehensive monitoring tool like [Netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud) to gather realtime statistics.

https://www.netdata.cloud